# Why does p =\= 'p' return an error in SWI-prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have question with single quote atom. 
While p == 'p' returns true, why is p =\= 'p' not returning false? it gives me an error saying 'p' is not a function.

Comment: @lurker Thanks! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`==` checks term equality](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%3D)/2), while [`=\=` checks arithmetical inequality](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D%5C%3D)/2). Being as `p` is not a number, Prolog treats it as an arithmetic expression, trying to find out its arithmetic value:

> 1 ?- p == 'p'. 
>   true. 
>    
>   2 ?- p =/= 'p'. 
>   ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected 
>   ERROR: p 
>   ERROR: ** here ** 
>   ERROR:  =/= 'p' .  
>    
>   2 ?- p =\= 'p'. 
>   ERROR: =\=/2: **Arithmetic**: `p/0' is not a function 
>    
>   3 ?-